# getsockopt failed strangely: Operation not permitted in Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, docker-swarm, haproxy

I'm getting a strange error when trying to start up a docker-swarm with docker-compose. I'm trying to use the following (brief) tutorial to convert a docker-compose swarm using HAProxy to use letsencrypt ssl. You can see the tutorial here: http://blog.armstrongconsulting.com/?p=392.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  back:
    image: patientplatypus/lowtechback:latest
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      restart_policy:
       condition: on-failure
       max_attempts: 5
       window: 120s
    networks:
      - web
  front:
    image: patientplatypus/lowtechfront:latest
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    depends_on:
      - back
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      restart_policy:
       condition: on-failure
       max_attempts: 5
       window: 120s
    networks:
      - web
  proxy:
    # image: dockercloud/haproxy
    image: nmarus/haproxy-certbot
    depends_on:
      - back
      - front
    environment:
      - BALANCE=leastconn
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose:
      - "8080"
      - "3000"
      - "5000"
    cap_add:
      - ALL
      - NET_ADMIN
    volumes:
      - ./data/config:/config
      - ./data/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certs:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/certs.d
    networks:
      - web
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
networks:
  web:
    driver: overlay
```

In `./data/config/haproxy.cfg` there is a file that has configuration options for haproxy to use ssl. The only relevant change I made to the default config (you can see that here: https://hub.docker.com/r/nmarus/haproxy-certbot) that I made was this:

```
backend my_http_backend
  mode http
  balance leastconn
  option tcp-check
  option log-health-checks
  server back back:5000 check port 5000
  server front front:80 check port 80
```

to route to my own containers.

When I run the following commands (as root):

```
 docker swarm init \
   --advertise-addr MY_IP_ADD_SS
docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yaml prod2
```

I get the following:

```
root@ubuntu-1gb-nyc3-01:/lowteck# docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                 PORTS
ko2xkerpki9f        prod2_back          replicated          3/3                 patientplatypus/lowtechback:latest    *:5000->5000/tcp
rly8rrb5uiht        prod2_front         replicated          3/3                 patientplatypus/lowtechfront:latest   *:80->3000/tcp
nuf7219sxteu        prod2_proxy         replicated          0/1                 nmarus/haproxy-certbot:latest         *:8080->8080/tcp
root@ubuntu-1gb-nyc3-01:/lowteck# docker service logs prod2_proxy
prod2_proxy.1.y2eagrgn52fg@ubuntu-1gb-nyc3-01    | getsockopt failed strangely: Operation not permitted
prod2_proxy.1.ycbj0rojv2tl@ubuntu-1gb-nyc3-01    | getsockopt failed strangely: Operation not permitted
prod2_proxy.1.y4mt1es20q0v@ubuntu-1gb-nyc3-01    | getsockopt failed strangely: Operation not permitted
prod2_proxy.1.ohopcbdmgvwt@ubuntu-1gb-nyc3-01    | getsockopt failed strangely: Operation not permitted
```

As far as I can tell I've set the `cap_add` option to allow this operation in the proxy container, I've run the swarm command as root, and I should have read/write/execute permissions on my `haproxy.cfg` file. Why am I getting this strange error?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think cap_add is supported by docker swarm.  Here's the related stack overflow answer: https://serverfault.com/a/824548.

Comment: Correct cap_add isn't supported in swarm https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#cap_add-cap_drop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the bind-mounts are causing that problem in haproxy, or just something wrong with the `nmarus/haproxy-certbot` image.

In Swarm it's recommended you use docker volume's to store persistent data like the certs and configs generated by your container. If using multiple Swarm nodes, you need to use shared storage with something like http://rexray.io to ensure volumes are not "stuck" on one node.

Optionally, you could use Swarm Secrets and Configs to inject those things into containers if you're providing them to the container at start, but I'm guessing that image you're using generates them on the fly.

Also, `depends_on`, `cap_add`, and `expose` are not used by Swarm. See the [compose file doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) on each feature you want to use in the yaml.

Lastly, it looks like the image you're using doesn't support using the docker socket like you have mounted (you have two volumes: objects in the same service) and so you really should look at proxies that are "swarm aware" and can self-update based on services you deploy. [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) does this, and I [go through examples of using it in Swarm on GitHub](https://github.com/BretFisher/dogvscat).